# How to receive GenericMessage with Object payload instead of string from MessageCollector

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

I try to test message sending and receiving via `spring-cloud-stream` using `MessageCollector`.

When i am using native java serialization for stream cloud all works fine, but when i change serialization to json, MessageCollector returns me GenericMessage with `string` payload instead of `SomeObject` payload.

Configuration is

```
  cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

Test case:

```
    Message outMsg = new GenericMessage<SomeObject>(new SomeObject(1));
    someChannel.send(outMsg);
    GenericMessage<SomeObject> inMsg = (GenericMessage<SomeObject>) messageCollector.forChannel(someChannel).poll();

    Assert.assertTrue(inMsg.getPayload() instanceof SomeObject);
```

As a result Assertions is false. `inMsg` contains string payload (the string contains valid json representation of SomeObject).

**And my question is:** How can i receive `GenericMessage` with SomeObject payload from `MessageCollector`?

*production environment works fine without explicitly mapping to `SomeObject`.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But that's correct. The channel is for `output` to the messaging broker. So, we have just serialized your `payload` into the JSON and it is ready to be delivered. That's why you use everything OK in production because you have a messaging broker in between and the proper deserializer for the `input` on another side. This `messageCollector` approach is exactly for assertion what we are going to send to the broker, so adding some additional deserialization functionality is out of scope this utility.

Only what I may suggest you is to use Jackson `ObjectMapper` directly on the `payload` after receiving `inMsg` from the collector:

```
Message outMsg = new GenericMessage<SomeObject>(new SomeObject(1));
someChannel.send(outMsg);
GenericMessage<String> inMsg = (GenericMessage<String>) messageCollector.forChannel(someChannel).poll();
SomeObject someObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inMsg.getPayload(), SomeObject.class);

Assert.assertTrue(someObject instanceof SomeObject);
```

Comment: is JSON the default contentType? I'm having the same problem, and I haven't defined cloud.stream.default.contentType in my configuration. I also don't understand why the usual (non-test) usage receives the properly-typed message.

Comment: Yes. The JSON is a default content type. So, everything tries to be serialized before sending to the messaging broker. See Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#content-type-management